# Why is touchevent not in the middle of the finger press?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mouseevent, touch-event

I'm listening for touchevents and when I adjust the `pageX`/`pageY` values with `layerX`/`layerY`, the point shows as at the top of the circle from my touch (my finger), not the middle.

```
//pageX = 310, layerX = -9. This is exactly in the middle of the touch circle horizontally
touchEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX + touchEvent.layerX

//pageY = 90, layerY = -34. This is exactly at the top of the touch circle!
touchEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX + touchEvent.layerX
```

When I check for the radius of the touch circle, all I see is a radius of 1: `webkitRadiusX: 1`, `webkitRadiusY: 1` (from a `console.dir( touchEvent);`).

I have three questions:

1. Why is the radius "1" when touching the screen (Windows 8/Chrome) shows a circle with a big radius and the "x" is at the middle of that?
2. Why do I need to combine layer and page coordinates to get the same values as what I'd get on mouseEVent's layer coordinates alone?
3. What is the proper way to get the point within an element on a touchEvent vs mouseevent?

**THE CODE**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Touch Test</title>
        <script src="touch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="touchBox" class="touchBox" style="position: relative; top: 19px; left: 0px; width: 638px; height: 142px; border: solid 1px #000000;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**touch.js**

```
window.Touch = {
    init: function()
    {
        Touch.dom = document.getElementById( "touchBox" );

        //Start listening
        Touch.dom.addEventListener( "touchstart", Touch.mouseDown, false );
        Touch.dom.addEventListener( "mousedown", Touch.mouseDown, false );
    },

    getPoint: function(touchEvent)
    {
        var x, y;

        //Using touch events
        if ( touchEvent.changedTouches && touchEvent.changedTouches[ 0 ] )
        {
            //Get the offset of the dom object
            var offsety = Touch.dom.offsetTop || 0;
            var offsetx = Touch.dom.offsetLeft || 0;

            //The points within the dom object
            x = touchEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX - offsetx + touchEvent.layerX;
            y = touchEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY - offsety + touchEvent.layerY;
        }

        //Get points relative to the layer
        else if ( touchEvent.layerX || 0 == touchEvent.layerX )
        {
            x = touchEvent.layerX;
            y = touchEvent.layerY;
        }

        //Get the points relative to the dom object
        else if ( touchEvent.offsetX || 0 == touchEvent.offsetX )
        {
            x = touchEvent.offsetX;
            y = touchEvent.offsetY;
        }

        return { x: x, y: y };
    },

    mouseDown: function(mouseEvent)
    {
        //Make sure it doesn't move the page
        mouseEvent.preventDefault();
        mouseEvent.stopPropagation();

        //Get the point
        var point = Touch.getPoint( mouseEvent );

        //Draw the point
        var pointDiv = document.createElement( "div" );
        pointDiv.style.width = "3px";
        pointDiv.style.height = "3px";
        pointDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
        pointDiv.style.left = point.x + "px";
        pointDiv.style.top = point.y + "px";
        pointDiv.style.position = "absolute";
        Touch.dom.appendChild( pointDiv );

        //Print the point
        console.dir( point );
    }
};
window.addEventListener( "load", Touch.init );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the offset. It's not needed. The offset appears to be incorporated into `layerX/Y`. So change the code for touch events to this:

```
//Using touch events
if ( touchEvent.changedTouches && touchEvent.changedTouches[ 0 ] )
{
    //The points within the dom object
    x = touchEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX + touchEvent.layerX;
    y = touchEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY + touchEvent.layerY;
}
```